# Python: KeyError/IOError with urllib.urlopen

Tags: python, json, urllib, urlopen

I am trying to pass some text to this [readability API](http://ipeirotis.appspot.com/readability-api.html) like so:

```
text = 'this reminds me of the Dutch 2001a caravan full of smoky people Auld Lang Syne'
# construct Readability Metrics API url
request_url = 'http://ipeirotis.appspot.com/readability/GetReadabilityScores?format=json&text=%s' % text
request_url = urllib.quote_plus(request_url.encode('utf-8'))
# make request
j = json.load(urllib.urlopen(request_url))
```

I get this error on the last line though:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://ipeirotis.appspot.com/readability/GetReadabilityScores?format=json&text=this+reminds+me+of+the+Dutch+2001a+caravan+full+of+smoky+people+Auld+Lang+Syne'

However, the URL in the error is valid and returns a response when you visit it. How do I encode the URL so that I can use urlopen? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quoting the full url, including the http:// and what not. If you try to print the actually value of request_url, you get

```
>>> print request_url
http%3A%2F%2Fipeirotis.appspot.com%2Freadability%2FGetReadabilityScores%3Fformat
%3Djson%26text%3Dthis+reminds+me+of+the+Dutch+2001a+caravan+full+of+smoky+people
+Auld+Lang+Syne
```

Which is not what you want. You only want to quote the parts that you want to be a single argument to the website. I tried the following and it seemed to work:

```
text = 'this reminds me of the Dutch 2001a caravan full of smoky people Auld Lang Syne'
# construct Readability Metrics API url
request_url = 'http://ipeirotis.appspot.com/readability/GetReadabilityScores?format=json&text=%s' % urllib.quote_plus(text.encode('utf-8'))
# make request
j = json.load(urllib.urlopen(request_url))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes much more sense!

Answer (score 1):

Use urllib.urlencode to encode only the query string, like so:

```
request_url = 'http://ipeirotis.appspot.com/readability/GetReadabilityScores?%s' % urllib.urlencode({'format': 'json', 'text': text})
```

Encoding the entire URL will encode the slashes and colons, and you want those to remain unencoded so it will be parsed properly as a URL (and not mistaken for a local file).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I love this site!